# Jquery Mobile - Mutilple transitions not working when page loaded via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-ajax

I developing a application in jqm, which have two page welcome page and a survey page. Welcome page has a link to survey page.Survey page has a multistage layout with all question in one page with next-pre button which has a slide transaction effect. 
Now when i come from clicking the link form welcome page next-pre button don't work but when i refresh the survey page manually it work properly

Comment: If you're using multi-html file, JQM will load first page of each html file. You either put each question/page in separate html files or combine all pages in one html file.